# What is the use of removeRange method of AbstractList class in subclasses

Tags: java, list, effective-java

In Effective Java, it is stated that

> removeRange method is of no interest to end users of a List
> implementation. It is provided solely to make it easy for subclasses
> to provide a fast clear method on sublists. In the absence of the
> removeRange method, subclasses would have to make do with quadratic
> performance when the clear method was invoked on sublists or rewrite
> the entire subList mechanism from scratch—not an easy task!

Please have a look at this [link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA88#v=onepage&q&f=false). Last paragraph. It says In the **absence** of the **removeRange** method, subclasses would have to make do with **quadratic performance**.

Please explain why author said this.

Comment: Well, if there were no `removeRange` method, implementing classes would have to deal with a solution that would be bound by O(N^2).

Comment: @EvanKnowles, I understand what quadratic performance means. I asked why is it quadratic

Comment: Technically, you started asking about the use of such method, in your title, not about the quadratic performance, so it can be confusing.

Comment: @Gnoupi Yes Sir, Please forgive me for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AbstractList` already provides a default implementation of `subList(int from, int to)`. The `clear()` method of this default sub-list simply calls `removeRange(...)` on its parent list.

Without `removeRange(...)`, the sub-list would have to use an iterator, calling `next()` and `remove()` repeatedly. But removing elements via `Iterator.remove()` might have linear performance - e.g. `ArrayList` has to left-shift all subsequent elements in its internal array every time an element is removed. Calling a *linear* method repeatedly results in a *quadratic* performance.

*Note*: The `removeRange(...)` implementation in `AbstractList` uses an iterator by default. So subclasses should override it to provide a more performant implementation (if available).

The advantage: To optimize performance, subclasses have to implement `removeRange` only, and they can keep the default implementation of `subList(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

> In the absence of the `removeRange` method, subclasses would have to make do with quadratic performance when the clear method was invoked on sublists

The author makes an assumption that implementations would have to call `remove` for each element of a range. In some implementations, such as `ArrayList`s, `remove` must copy everything after the element being removed, which has O(n) complexity. Assuming that the range size is `r`, the overall complexity of a loop implementation would be O(n*r), which is quadratic.

An implementation of `removeRange` specific to `ArrayList` has O(n) complexity, because you can copy the to its new position in a single loop.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I could not accept your answer. But please believe me your answer is as brilliant as the answer I accepted. I will go through the questions you answered and award you +25 or more immediately. Thanks